# Detecting SSH timeout

Tags: bash, ssh, error-handling

Is there any way I could trigger a bash script when ssh times out?

I have an alias to set the tmux title when starting ssh. The alias also includes a title change *after* the ssh session, which works if I do a clean exit, but if the session times out, the rest of the alias doesn't run.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap `ssh` with a shell script instead of an alias:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 echo "Setting up tmux and stuff..."
 # set up tmux and stuff

 ssh "$@"

 echo "Cleaning up..."
 # clean up
```

Comment: The only thing, it's not great with nested ssh connections. Otherwise it works perfect.